# Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:

Tags: python, django

I was setting Django up to use PostgresQL and for some reason, it won't connect it keep giving me this error:

> Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
>   'mysql', 'oracle', 'sqlite3'

here's the code for it in setting.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'DBNAME',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'DBPW',
        'HOST': 'localhost'
    }
}
```

I had the exact same code in a different project and it works perfectly fine!

Comment: do you use docker? what's your postgresql server port?

Comment: @KhashayarGhamati no I installed PG normally from http://postgresql.org then used pgAdmin for creating my db, port is 5432

Comment: Check your PG port and add it in django `DATABASE` dictionary

Comment: @KhashayarGhamati you mind showing me a link to how to do it from their docs? :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to `pip install psycopg2`, looks like the Postgres adaptor is not installed

Comment: I've both psycopg2 and psycopg2-binary installed and it doesn't seem to solve it still!

Comment: what platform are you trying this on? Is `psycopg2`installed in the same virtualenv that your project uses?

Comment: I'm using windows, and yes it's I just checked with pip freeze and it exists

Comment: its definitely an adaptor install issue, if the Postgres adaptor was installed, you should have seen a message like `Try using django.db.backends.XXX, where XXX is one of: 
    'dummy', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 
'sqlite3' `

Comment: can you check if you are in the virtualenv? `pip freeze`might be returning modules installed in the system

Answer (score 0):

use this config  instead of your config:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'DBNAME',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'DBPW',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '',
 }
}
```

your `ENGINE` is not correct.

Comment: I did try it but nothing changed! it gave me the exact same error